# get just one attribute from json array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$proj_document = [{"name":"project__1MfEqp.jpg", "type":"image\/jpeg", "size":4792, "path":"uploads\/project__1MfEqp.jpg"}];
```

I want the name alone which means, `project__1MfEqp.jpg`

I used

```
$proj_document[0]['name'] and 
$proj_document[0]->name;
```

but didnt work for me.how to get name alone from the above json format? can anyone help me?? thanks.

Comment: try `echo $project_document[0]->name`

Comment: I seems `$proj_document = [{"name":"project__1MfEqp.jpg", "type":"image/jpeg", "size":4792, "path":"uploads/project__1MfEqp.jpg"}];` it is not valid code in `php`

Comment: I tried. didnt work out for me

Answer (score 3):

You need to do like below:-

```
<?php
$proj_document = '[{"name":"project__1MfEqp.jpg", "type":"image\/jpeg", "size":4792, "path":"uploads\/project__1MfEqp.jpg"}]';
 $proj_document_array = json_decode($proj_document); // convert json data into array
 echo "<pre/>";print_r($proj_document_array); // print that array to check it's format
 echo $proj_document_array[0]->name; // get the name attribute
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/407953

Comment: @cathy123  its your responsibility to check the answer and mark and up-vote the answer which is correct and more descriptive for you. Please do it. It will help others. Stack work in this way only.